# What is wrong with my sqlite3 script?

Tags: python, sqlite

```
c = conn.cursor()                                                       
c.executescript("""                                                     
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dvdlist (                                    
        title text,                                                         
        barcode,                                                            
        added_date text,                                                    
        out numeric,                                                        
        borrower text,                                                      
        price real                                                          
        );                                                                  

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userdb (                                     
        username text,                                                      
        password text,                                                      
        address text,                                                       
        phone text,                                                         
        email text,                                                         
        borrowed integer
        );                                                                  

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS staffdb (                                    
        username text,                                                      
        password text,                                                      
        address text,                                                       
        phone text,                                                         
        email text,                                                         
        group integer
        );                                                                  
    """)
```

Traceback says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "shopdatabase.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.__db_init()
  File "shopdatabase.py", line 108, in __db_init
    """)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "group": syntax error
```

I have looked up the data types in sqlite at http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html, I am not quite sure what is going on. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`group` is a [reserved keyword](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) (it is part of the SQL language). You'll need to quote it if you want to use it as a column name:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS staffdb (                                    
    username text,                                                      
    password text,                                                      
    address text,                                                       
    phone text,                                                         
    email text,                                                         
    'group' integer
    );
```

You can use single quotes (`'group'`), double quotes (`"group"`) or square brackets or backticks (`[group]` and `` `group` ``), but the latter two forms are only supported for compatibility with non-compliant database engines.

You'll have to quote the name anywhere you use it in a SQL statement:

```
SELECT 'group' FROM staffdb WHERE username=?
```

for example.

Answer (score 2):

Group is one of the [reserved keywords](https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html). You can't use it this way.

And as @MartijnPieters states in his answer, you can wrap `group` with quotes to make the problem solved.

Comment: You can if you quote it.